# How to solve this non-linear equation?

Tags: equation-solving

```
b=12

a=2.787

solve[b/x-((1-(a*(((b x)/(b+2 x))^(4/3))))^(-2/3))-
    ((1+(a*(((b x)/(b+2 x))^(4/3))))^(-2/3))==0,x]
```

[image: output]

I gave the above code and the output came out as shown in figure. So how do i know the value of `x`??

Comment: Without investigating analysis: what makes you think there exists a closed analytic solution? You can just use e.g. `FindRoot` or `NSolve` to find numerical roots...

Comment: You need to use Solve (and not solve). @Lukas is right though. There doesn't seem to be an analytic solution.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @PatrickS Completely overlooked the missing capital...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b = 12; a = 2.787;
equ = b/x - ((1 - (a*(((b x)/(b + 2 x))^(4/3))))^(-2/3)) - 
((1 + (a*(((b x)/(b + 2 x))^(4/3))))^(-2/3))
```

$$-\frac{1}{\left(76.5676 \left(\frac{x}{2 x+12}\right)^{4/3}+1\right)^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{\left(1-76.5676 \left(\frac{x}{2 x+12}\right)^{4/3}\right)^{2/3}}+\frac{12}{x}$$

```
Plot[equ, {x, -0.1, 0.6}]
```

[image]

```
FindInstance[equ == 0, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> 0.498821}}